# how to draw rectangle canvas?

Tags: android, methods, view, android-canvas, draw

In this example code I give a nice square in the form I want. canvas.drawRect (100, 300, 600, 800, paint); values work. But what I want is to call these values from the Activity class. So I want to send these values to the Draw class in the activity class. How can I do that ? For example, I want to send an activity class as drawRect (100,100,100,100, Color.BLUE). I do not want to write these values in the Draw class.

Draw.java

```
public class Draw extends View {

Paint paint;
Path path;

public Draw(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public Draw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public Draw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public void init(){
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawRect(100, 300, 600, 800, paint);
 }
 }
```

Activity.java

```
    constraintLayout=findViewById(R.id.constraint);
    Draw draw = new Draw(this);
    constraintLayout.addView(draw);
```

Comment: You add a function to Draw that takes these values, stores them, then invalidates the view.

Comment: pass those value in constructor of Draw.

Comment: @ABK
    public Draw(Context context,float left, float top, float right, float bottom) {
        super(context);
        this.left = left;
        this.top = top;
        this.right = right;
        this.bottom = bottom;
        init();
    } but how do I pass drawRect. I use duggu codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make method and pass value from activity to draw class:-

```
Draw draw = new Draw(this,100, 300, 600, 800);
constraintLayout.addView(draw);
```

**Draw class**

```
public class Draw extends View {

Paint paint;
Path path;

float left; 
float top; 
float right; 
float bottom;

public Draw(Context context,float left, float top, float right, float bottom) {
    super(context);
    this.left = left;
    this.top = top;
    this.right = right;
    this.bottom = bottom;
    init();
}

public Draw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public Draw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public void init(){
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
 }
 }
```

Comment: I applied what they said, but did not work. When we give those values in the init method, it does not go anywhere. I do not know exactly what you want to do

Comment: please check or do changes accordingly

Comment: I applied but //canvas.drawRect (100, 300, 600, 800, paint); comment line is not working. I just want to send values from the activity class. How can I send canvas.drawRect in the Draw class to the values I wrote in the Activity class?

Comment: Thank you very much everything ! Finally if I send the picture from the activity class what should I do? for example Draw draw = new Draw (this, COLOR.BLACK, 100, 300, 600, 800);

Answer (score 0):

You can create local variables for the bounds and set them using setters or init function before adding that view to a viewgroup.( `constraintLayout.addView(draw)` in your case

Comment: no use of comment because same this code constraintLayout=findViewById(R.id.constraint);
    Draw draw = new Draw(this);
    constraintLayout.addView(draw);

Comment: sorry, but I didn't get you.